# Collection View Not Showing Data

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit

My goal is to display data coming from a web service called News API into a collection view controller. Below is the data model and network manager.

```
struct News: Codable {
    var status: String?
    var totalResults: Int?
    var articles: [Article]?
    var article: Article?
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case status = "status"
        case totalResults = "totalResults"
        case articles = "articles"
    }
}

// MARK: - Article
struct Article: Codable {
    var source: Source?
    var author: String?
    var title: String?
    var articleDescription: String?
    var url: String?
    var urlToImage: String?
    var publishedAt: String?
    var content: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case source = "source"
        case author = "author"
        case title = "title"
        case articleDescription = "description"
        case url = "url"
        case urlToImage = "urlToImage"
        case publishedAt = "publishedAt"
        case content = "content"
    }
}

// MARK: - Source
struct Source: Codable {
    var id: ID?
    var name: Name?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "id"
        case name = "name"
    }
}

enum ID: String, Codable {
    case engadget = "engadget"
    case techcrunch = "techcrunch"
    case theVerge = "the-verge"
}

enum Name: String, Codable {
    case engadget = "Engadget"
    case lifehackerCOM = "Lifehacker.com"
    case techCrunch = "TechCrunch"
    case theVerge = "The Verge"
}


class NetworkManger{
    
    static let shared = NetworkManger()
    private let baseURL: String
    private var  apiKeyPathCompononent :String
     private init(){
        self.baseURL = "https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=NFT&sortBy=popularity&"
        self.apiKeyPathCompononent = "apiKey=d32071cd286c4f6b9c689527fc195b03"
    }
    private var jsonDecoder:JSONDecoder = {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
            return decoder
        }()

    
    func getArticles() {
        AF.request(self.baseURL + self.apiKeyPathCompononent, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil, interceptor: nil).response { (responseData) in
                guard let data = responseData.data else {return}
            do {
                let news = try self.jsonDecoder.decode(News.self, from: data)
                let nc = NotificationCenter.default
                nc.post(name: Notification.Name("didFinishParsing"), object: nil)
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
                
            }
        }    
}
```

It can display data from the web service to the console. The problem is that it can not show data to the collection view in NewsVC. I've done all necessary steps such as implementing the collection view data source, using an observer to alert the NewsVC that the JSON is parsed, setting the collection view layout, and registering the cell, but nothing seems to work. The code below is the NewVc and News grid; News Vc is meant to show the contents of the.

```
class NewsVC: UIViewController {
    var news = [Article]()
    
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configureCollection()
        NetworkManger.shared.getArticles()
    }
    
    func configureCollection(){
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        let collectionviewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        collectionviewFlowLayout.scrollDirection  = .vertical
        collectionviewFlowLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 188.0, height: 264.0)
        collectionviewFlowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10.0
        collectionView.collectionViewLayout = collectionviewFlowLayout
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(refreshcollectionView), name: Notification.Name("didFinishParsing"), object: nil)

    }

    @objc func refreshcollectionView(_ notification:Notification) {
        guard let news = notification.object as? Article else { return}
        print("News == \(news)")
        self.news = [news]
        print("Coount == \(self.news.count)")
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
   


extension NewsVC:UICollectionViewDataSource , UICollectionViewDelegate{

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        news.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionCell", for: indexPath) as! NewsGridCell
        let stories = news[indexPath.item]
        cell.setCells(stories)
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

        return cell
    }
    
class NewsGridCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var newsImage: UIImageView!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var newsDescription: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var author: UILabel!
    
    
    func setCells(_ news:Article){
        upDateUI(newDescription:news.articleDescription, author: news.author)
    }
    
    private func upDateUI(newDescription:String? , author:String?){
        self.newsDescription.text = newDescription
        self.author.text = author
    }
    
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try instead of

```
nc.post(name: Notification.Name("didFinishParsing"), object: nil)
```

send

```
nc.post(name: Notification.Name("didFinishParsing"), object: news)
```

Then instead of

```
guard let news = notification.object as? Article else { return}
```

write

```
guard let news = notification.object as? News else { return}
print("News == \(news)")
self.news = news.articles
```

Comment: Thank you so much it works. Can you please explain your approach ?

Comment: As you can see you didn't send News data to the CollectionView data source. You sent nil instead. Then you parse Article instead of News. If you send News then you get News. But you sent News and expect Article.  Something like that. I think you made typos.

Comment: Since the class Articles contains the properties of the JSON, I assumed it will work. When it comes to parsing JSON and displaying it in any view controller what class should I use from the data model News or Articles ?

Comment: It depends on requirements. In your case, you need articles to show them but the server returns news. Just one piece of news (in your case). You should parse the news and then use articles as a model for collectionview. Btw i guess the "var article: Article?" in News structure is redundant. And i suppose the server returns an array of news. Find out it. If so you should use sectioned collectionview. i think so.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the snippets, the code looks like it should works but it doesn't. In that case I would add `debugPrint(#function)` to check if following methods are executed:

```
NewsVC -> collectionView(_:numberOfItemsInSection:)
NewsVC -> collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)
NewsGridCell -> setCells(_:)
```

If those debugPrints print to the console then I would go to the "[View Hierarchy inspector](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/ExaminingtheViewHierarchy.html)" to examine presence and a view's sizes.